# Unable to pass data from ajax function after doing async false

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, ag-grid

I create a rest service and now I'm trying to create a gui with the data. Right now, my index.html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="loadingGrid.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sortGrid.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ag-grid-enterprise.js"></script>
  </head>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body> 
<div id="myGrid" style="width: 100%; height: 71%;" class="ag-blue">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my file1.js looks like this:

```
var rootURL = "http://localhost:8181/RestServiceProject/rest/WebService/getdata";
function findByName() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: rootURL,
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function(json){  return json;    }
    });
}
(function(){
 var columnDefs = [
     {headerName: "CLIENT", field: "CLIENT_ACRONYM", width: 150, unSortIcon: true},
    {headerName: "SYM", field: "SYM", width: 150, unSortIcon: true, filter: 'set'},

];

var gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    rowData: null,
    enableSorting: true,
    enableFilter: true,
    enableColResize: true

};

// setup the grid after the page has finished loading
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
    new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);

    // do http request to get our sample data - not using any framework to keep the example self contained.
    // you will probably use a framework like JQuery, Angular or something else to do your HTTP calls.
   var jsondata = findByName()
var json = JSON.parse(jsondata);

function isNumeric(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

var parsedData = json.map(function(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(memo, key) {
        var value = obj[key];
        memo[key] = isNumeric(value) ? Number(value) : value;
        return memo;
    }, {})
});

gridOptions.api.setRowData(parsedData);
autoSizeAll();

});
})()
```

So, when go to localhost:8181/RestServiceProject, it goes to `myGrid` div. Then in file1.js I have made a jQuery ajax function, where I want to return data on success so I've made async: false, I'm calling the `findByName()` function below in file1.js and saving the value returned in var json as  `var json = findByName()`. But json variable is coming `undefined`. Why is this so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're returning from the callback function, that's not the same as returning from `findByName()`. You can do what you want by setting a variable in the callback function and then returning that from the containing function.

```
function findByName() {
    var returnVal;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: rootURL,
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function(json){  returnVal = json;    }
    });
    return returnVal;
}
```

However, it would be better if you designed your application so it worked with asynchronous AJAX. Synchronous AJAX is deprecated. See [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: If OP takes your suggestion and decides to use async ajax, then I don't think your option will work since returnVal won't get set to json until successful completion of the ajax

Comment: That's true. My advice was to redesign using async *instead* of using that code.

Answer (score 0):

Your findByName function isn't returning anything that is why your jsondata variable isn't holding any data. What is better is to run the function where you are setting the data in the success function like so:

```
function findByName() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: rootURL,
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function(data){  
             var json = JSON.parse(data);

             function isNumeric(n) {
                 return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
             }

             var parsedData = json.map(function(obj) {
                 return Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(memo, key) {
                     var value = obj[key];
                     memo[key] = isNumeric(value) ? Number(value) : value;
                     return memo;
                 }, {})
             });

             gridOptions.api.setRowData(parsedData);
             autoSizeAll();

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will work. `$.ajax` returns a `jqXHR`, not the value returned by the callback function.

Comment: You are probably right, I was recently coding with Angular 2 and their ajax/http method returned data so I thought it might work. I will edit with a proper solution